# PHP Convert number with leading zeros to string

Tags: php, string, integer

I've not been able to find a question that addresses this aspect of integer to string conversion in PHP so...
I have a file in which one field holds some numbers of length 3, 4 or 5 digits
I need to standardise all to 4 digits.
If the numbers are 123, 1234, 12345 then to standardise I add a trailing zero to the first, do nothing to the second and round the third: round(12345/10)
So far so good.  The problem is that the file includes some numbers with significant leading zeros 023, 0234, 02346.
I need to retain the leading zero, I want the output to be 0230, 0234, 0235
I thought I could force the field to be a string, remove the first character if it was zero, do the calculations on the remaining number then left-pad the number as a string with a leading zero
The problem with that when I try to convert a number with a leading zero to a string the leading zero seems to be interpreted as indicating the number is in octal. 
strval(0123) > 83
(string)0123 > 83

I've got the task working by an edit to the source data file to replace any leading zeros with a hash so the field becomes a string.  Then my process becomes: if the field starts with # strip it, do the calculations then prepend a zero. Surely there's a better solution, a different way to read the file perhaps?  I'm using fgetcsv

Comment: You need to show us the code you are using that isn't functioning the way you want it to.

Comment: I don't see the problem. When I read a numeric string from file, it converts to integer ok - `$x = '0123'; var_dump((int)$x);` -> `123`. I do not see, where the octal representation happens in Your case. Please show us the code.

Comment: Changing 12345  to 1235 for formatting does not sound right. I hope these are not important numbers.

Answer (score -2):

I would add the next biggest number that is 1 followed by zeroes to your number e.g.

0672 --> +1000

to get 1672

Then, convert that to a string and change the character at position one to a zero again.

That's my way... I'm pretty new to PHP so there's probably a more sophisticated answer but if all else fails, it works.

Answer (score -3):

you can use following code

```
$yourInt = 253;
$intWithZeros = sprintf("%05d", $yourInt); // result 00253
```

you can change number of characters changing value `5` in `"%05d"`

Comment: This will fail if the number starts with leading `0` !

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui i think that are 2 separate questions here. Parsing a `0` leading string to an int does not seem to be a problem (see @Roman Hocke). And this answer seems fine to output it 0 padded.

Comment: @RolandStarke, it's not really clear what the OP is asking, but if the input is an `Int` starting with `00`, `intval(00253)` will give us `171` !

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I think the input is a string so the octal notation `00253` should not be a concern here. As `inval('00253')` or `(int) '00253'` give the correct number.